# Training and testing AdaBoost for low probability classification

Tags: classification, class-imbalance

I have a dataset that I want to classify as fraud/not fraud and I have many weak learners. My concern is that there is much more fraud than not fraud, so my weak learners perform better than average, but none perform better than 50% accuracy in the complete set.

My question is whether I should set up testing and training sets that are half fraud and half not fraud or if I should just use a representative sample.

Comment: How many samples do you have of each? An alternative could be to try some outlier detection approach and test it against your fraud data.

Comment: bias–variance tradeoff should be there in training data.

Comment: Have you seen this question:https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6200/what-are-the-basic-approaches-for-balancing-a-dataset-for-machine-learning/6249#6249

Comment: You might also consider layering a cost-matrix over your classification algorithm, as there is an imbalance in the penalty for making different errors in classification.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use Adaboost in this context ?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that adding generated data to your data set will decrease the fraud/non fraud ration and make your dataset more representative / usable ?

At GenieLog, we are producing test data for designing and testing fraud detection tools. We our generator GEDIS Studio we can define regular profiles and fraudster profiles, instantiating each category to a customizable ratio (for ex. 2 % of customer will have fraudulent usage of generated events.)

We did it successfully for telecom CDR (http://www.gedis-studio.com/online-call-detail-records-cdr-generator.html) and Credit Card usages. There's a freely available access to the online generator on http://www.data-generator.com

I'm pretty sure that even if the tool is not matching your needs at least the approach can be valuable. Otherwise I would be interested to read any objection :)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Training set must represent the dataset your application/algorithm is actually going to face. I suggest you to take a representative sample instead of dividing the training and test set with exactly half fraud an half non-fraud. But please make sure that the training set contains both positive and negative example for fraud for your classifier to perform better.

Comment: This is true for your test set, but not training. Oversampling is necessary for problems like these since the vast majority of instances will not be fraud.

Answer (score 0):

In situations where a particular class is really a minority, I suggest using rare category detection. In this particular case of fraud/non-fraud, fraud is a rare category. Its an active field of research - Refere to [Rare Category Detection](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Rare%20category%20detection&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ved=0CBsQgQMwAGoVChMI3P2tg-LZxgIV0DCICh0jVAtS)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it depends on your data set. There are many ways to handle unbalanced data sets, just search, for example https://www.quora.com/In-classification-how-do-you-handle-an-unbalanced-training-set . I think that the simplest way is to use the same distribution of classes in the train and test sets.

If you have really small amount of minority class you can try [one-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification).